# $x_{n+1}=\sin(x_{n})$ and $x_n\in C$. When $x_1$ is in what range, $x_{n}$ will converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, analysis, complex-numbers

It's a question from https://www.zhihu.com/question/490721413. It easy to know when $x_1\in\mathbb{R}$ or $x_1=(k+1/2)\pi+iy$ , $x_n$is convergent,and when $x_1=k\pi+iy(y\neq 0)$ , $x_n$is divergent. In consideration of $\sinh(x)/x>1$ , $x_n$ is divergent when $x_1=\sin(ix)$.

Comment: Since $\lvert\cos(z)\rvert>1$ at all nonreal fixed points $z=\sin(z)$, we know the only possibilities to converge to those nonreal fixed points is if it will land there in finite time.  That leaves only $z_n\to 0$ to consider, which is locally described by Leau-Fatou flower theorem, but I'm not sure if we actually can give a global description.

Comment: Hmm.... $x_n$ **diverges** when $x_1 = k\pi + iy$ and **converges** when $x_1 = (k+\frac12)\pi + iy$. I'm not familiar with this stuff, but I bet the region where $x_n$ converges is the black part of first image on Pual Bourke's [Julia Set of sin(z)](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/sinjulia/).